# Extracting Synonyms

Tags: rstudio, nltk, wordnet, corpus, vsm

1. I have ten txt files and generated a corpus of these files.
2. After creating my corpus i need to generate vector space model.
3. For VSM i preprocessed the corpus to remove stop words, number, punctuation etc...
4. Now i need to read the corpus and generate the synonyms against each keyword/Character/Word present in the corpus.
5. I am unable to use wordnet to get synonyms against each file present in my text corpus.

I want to generate synonyms of each word and append those keywords in the same file..

Comment: Do you an snippet of code? Do you rely on a particular library outside nltk?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969653/extracting-synonyms-using-wordnet

Comment: Dear here is the code in above link i am trying to do.. I am using Wordnet Library to get synonyms and other libraries of NLTK to clean my textual data.